# Send email when a user registers Rest api

Tags: plugins, email

currently using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/ and there is a section where if you want to send a user an email when he/she registers (using wordpress as a headless CMS)

```
add_action('wp_rest_user_user_register', 'user_registered');
function user_registered($user) {
    // Do Something
}
```

already set up WP Mail SMTP plugin so it overrides the wp_mail function

the question is: how can I get the email of the registered user to send him/her an email using the wp_mail function ?

Comment: Have you checked, what exactly `$user` is you're getting passed? If it is an object of the [`WP_User`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) class, it should be trivial to get their mail address.

Comment: @kero I think it is a WP_User object but how can I make sure it is? like is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know the type of content that might be passed for the `$user` parameter, so let's test it out.

You will want to expand on these conditions and responses. This is just an example of the tests you probably want to make.

```
function user_registered( $user ) {
    // Check to make sure it's not an error.
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // This is how WordPress checks to make sure the user exists.
    // This could also apply to many other objects, though. 
    if ( ! isset( $user->ID ) ) {
        return; 
    }
    // This checks to make sure you're getting the expected user object fields.
    if ( ! isset( $user->user_email ) ) {
        // If you have a correct ID, you can still retrieve the user's fields.
        $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user->ID );
        // If the user doesn't exist, stop where you are.
        if ( ! $user ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: WordPress Website <admin@example.com>',
    );
    wp_mail( $user->user_email, 'Subject of email', 'Email body', $headers );
}
```